# What is the most effective way to embed a PDF document in an access report programmatically?

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, activex

I need to embed pdf documents with the address in a database to be embedded in sequential access reports. I am using access 2007.  My research shows equivocal results on this being a possibility.  I have included an ActiveX control with the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim filename As String
  filename = "C:\myFile"
  Me.AcroPDF1.LoadFile filename
End Sub
```

But the pdf does not load.

I have also tried:

```
  me.AcroPDF1.ControlSource = filename
```

but to no avail either.

Comment: so you want to lay text on top of a pdf is that correct?

Comment: My guess is that you would need some ActiveX component responsible for hosting the PDF document.

Comment: r00k, I just need a report to contain a pdf, and add a couple of controls to the report as well.

Comment: Mat's Mug this is what I have found the most.  Can you please elaborate on that.

Comment: I've no idea, I'm sorry. I don't even know if such an ActiveX component even exists - and if it does, it's probably not free. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ops.  I needed to use the .pdf extension.  And it works now!